# To connect pandas dataframe and dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to connect dataframe and dict like this the number of each cell is different so the number of "0","1" and so on is different total number of cells 16.

Comment: Hi.  We need a lot more information in order to help.  Can you show us an example of the data and what you hope to get in the table?  Can you show us what you have tried so far?  You might have luck with the `orient` parameter and `from_dict()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make some code, but, how about this ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
d = {"C": [7, 8, 9], "D": [10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(d)], axis=1)
print(df)
```